# Smoothing implicit plots with Maxima / wxMaxima

Tags: graphing-functions, maxima-software

I'm using Maxima for university mathematics and would like to improve the appearance of the graphs that it generates. Previously, when I'd used `plot2d` or `wxplot2d`, I'd see pretty, smooth plots of lines and parabolas. However, now that I'm graphing circles with `implicit_plot`, they're not nearly as smooth or pretty. It looks like a line that hasn't had any antialiasing applied, like so:

[`wximplicit_plot( (x-1)^2 + y^2 = 3, [x, -6, 6], [y, -6, 6] );`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXLEC.png)

Are there any flags I can pass to the `{wx,}implicit_plot` functions to antialias / smooth the lines drawn? I'm terribly spoilt by what I've seen PGF / TikZ can do and would like to make the same pretty graphics with (wx)Maxima.

Answer (score 1):

After you have loaded `implicit_plot`, evaluate

```
ip_grid : [100,100]$
wximplicit_plot( (x-1)^2 + y^2 = 3, [x, -6, 6], [y, -6, 6] )$
```

Calling `wximplicit_plot` like this will result in a smoother picture. The default value of `ip_grid` is [50, 50]; it defines the size of a grid used to build the curve.

Comment: Using `ip_grid` does provide some smoothing, but it doesn't quite smooth things the way I would hope. I'm guessing this just isn't supported.

Comment: No, apparently you won't get the TikZ-like vector output from it. Consulting the source of implicit_plot (sitting in /usr/share/maxima/5.42.2/share/contrib/implicit_plot.lisp for me) shows that the routine uses two sampling procedures, on the global and local level, to determine the sign changes of the expression to be plotted.